# Automated security audit for an application running on GAE / GWT application

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Does anyone knows if there is a tool out there to perform automated security checks for a Google App Engine application ?

There are docs out there on how to setup security for a GWT application running on Google App Engine but I was wondering if there is an automated tool I could use to check security holes

Thanks,

Hugues